# Modify how a node in drupal will look when viewed

Tags: drupal, module

I have some text stored in the body field of a custom content type called 'protocol'. What is stored in the body field is not exactly what I want to be seen when you view the node. Either as full or as a teaser. Forexample i might store something like this:

"[usage]Repeatable use of DNA template microarry for protein arraying by cell-free synthesis.[/usage]
[security considerations]Test security considerations[/security considerations]"

But what I want displayed when you view it would be this:

"Repeatable use of DNA template microarry for protein arraying by cell-free synthesis.
Test security considerations"

I taught this was what you could use hook_view for, so I tried this function in my module:

```
function molmethtag_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'protocol2' && $view_mode=='full') {

    $body = $node->body;
    $prot_array = _molmethtag_extract_data($body['und'][0]['value']);
    $protocol = '';
    foreach($prot_array as $tag => $prot_row) {
      $protocol .= "<div id='molmethtag_".$tag."'>".$prot_row."</div>";
    }                                                                                                                  
    $body['und'][0]['value'] = $protocol;

  }
}
```

But this didn't work out like I wanted. I hoped that the text saved in protocol would be displayed as the body when viewing but it showed the original text.

Does anybody know what I've done wrong? Is hook_view not used for this? What should I use/do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit confusing at first but the values you need to change for display are on the `$node->content` array:

```
$node->content['body'] = array(
  '#markup' => $protocol
);
```

`hook_node_view()` is a great place for this, but just for the sake of completeness you could also do something similar in `hook_preprocess_node()` if you wanted to.