# How to modify the body of a node via a module in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I created a module to highlight the code samples in the articles based on the highlight.js library. This library require code samples to be embed in <pre><code> ... </code></pre> tags. I don't want to add the <pre> tag when I write an article, because other highlighter libraries don't need it and I want to be able to switch library without modifying the articles. So I need to dynamically wrap <code> tags with <pre>. I tried to implement _node_view( and _node_view_alter( hooks without success.

My code look like

```
function highlight_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    $node->content['body']['und'][0]['safe_value'] = "test";
    $node->body['und'][0]['safe_value'] = "test";
    $node->content['body']['und'][0]['value'] = "test";
    $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = "test";
}

function highlight_node_view_alter($build, $node) {
    $build["body"]["#items"]["0"]["value"] = "TEST";
    $build["body"]["#items"]["0"]["safe_value"] = "TEST";
    $build["body"]["#formater"]["0"]["#markup"] = "TEST";
}
```

If I print the content in my template with

```
<pre>
    <?php    
        ob_start("minimal_htmlspecialchars_callback");
        print_r($content); 
        ob_end_flush();
    ?>
</pre>
```

I can confirm that all the values are correctly replaced by "test" but a call to

```
<?php print render($content['body']); ?>
```

still render the original content instead of "test"

What is the proper way to alter the content of an article from a module ?

Comment: Drupal 8 doesn't have a stable release yet and shouldn't be used other than for testing...are you sure you don't mean Drupal 7?

Comment: I know that Drupal 8 ins't ready yet but I like to experiment. I was developing my own very basic bloc system with Symfony2, so when I discovered that Drupal 8 was based on this framework I decided to give it a try (and so far I like it).

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully altered body field data, you have to place code in your module file like bellow. BTW I'm using drupal 8.2

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
/**
* Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view() for node entities.
*/

function module_name_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
   $build['body'][0]['#text'] = 'test by ajay'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution in a previous stackoverflow question ( [Modify how a node in drupal will look when viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120739/modify-how-a-node-in-drupal-will-look-when-viewed) ) and the following code work fine.

```
function highlight_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    $alteredBody = $node->body['und'][0]['safe_value'];
    $alteredBody = str_replace("<code>", "<pre><code>", $alteredBody);
    $alteredBody = str_replace("</code>", "</code></pre>", $alteredBody);

    $node->content['body'] = array(
        '#markup' => $node->body['und'][0]['safe_value'] = $alteredBody
    );
}
```

But I'm still not sure to fully understand the rendering system. So if somebody have a better solution or a more detailed explanation, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: This answer is not correct anymore, since Drupal 8 uses [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8) instead of `hook_node_view()`. The arguments are different, and so is the code this hook needs to implement.